# How to count the number of elements in multiple XML files?

Tags: python, xml

I'm transforming some xml files via xslt. At the end I would like to know the total number of documents processed. Each document is identified by the element `<entry>`

The xml structure is:

```xml
<root>
 <entry>
 </entry>
 <entry>
 </entry>
</root>
```

To do so I'm using the following solution in Python as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138699/how-to-find-the-number-of-elements-in-element-tree-in-python)

```py
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(myOutput):
        #print('Searching in : ',base)
        for directories in dirs:
            totalDirOut += 1
        for Files in files:
            totalFilesOut += 1
            if Files.endswith(('.xml')):
                doc = ET.parse(Files)
                root = doc.getroot()
                count = len(root.xpath(".//entry"))        

    
    print('Total number of files processed',totalFilesOut)
    print('Total Number of directories created',totalDirOut)
    print('Total:',(totalDirOut + totalFilesOut))
    print(count)
```

`myOutput` of course refers to the folder where the xml document are saved after the process.

However I'm having the following error:

`OSError: Error reading file '143727-143826@8ef36ec7-a3a5-4d62-acd5-1ee839f35aa5.xml': failed to load external entity "143727-143826@8ef36ec7-a3a5-4d62-acd5-1ee839f35aa5.xml"`

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps use `try` and `except` to skip over files that cannot be read?

Comment: Is your python script in the same directory as the xml files?

Comment: Hi steveo314. Nope.

Comment: @Pelide you need to account for that here `doc = ET.parse(Files)`

Comment: Getting count only without retrieving elements with this xpath: `tree.xpath('count(//*[local-name()="entry"])')`